# Delete first half of line in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I think the following can be done in a search & replace function.

How can I select until yahoo.com:

> overjoyedradica@yahoo.com:SQOVTJOHEN

and turn it to:

> :SQOVTJOHEN

Answer (score 4):

Use a regular expression. Replacing `^[^:]*:` with `:` should do what you need.

Breakdown:

```
^      Start of the line
[^:]*  Any character except colon, zero or more repetitions
:      Colon
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be achieved using [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), which are supported by Notepad++